# update another form textbox by login form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a login form. someone enter the project. it will write in textbox "Hi! + (username entered at login)". can you help me?
this what I try to do

```
Private Sub Login_Click()

   Dim form As [Form_Navigation Form]
   form.txtbox = Me.username

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need form object variable. 
Need to open [Navigation Form] before can set textbox value.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
Forms![Navigation Form].txtbox = "Hi, " & Me.username
```